# Monte Carlo Simulation of Probability of Shortfall - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a project in VBA to determine the probability of shortfall given a simulated series of terminal stock price values following the below formula

St = S0e(µ− σ^2/2)t+σBt where Bt is standard Brownian Motion as sqrt(t).

Below is the code and comments I have done so far

```
Option Explicit

'The following is a subroutine that generates the random terminal stock prices
'An array is passed into it by reference so that the populated values are available to the caller

Private Sub GenerateRandomTerminalStockPrices(ByVal sNaught As Double, _
                                              ByVal r As Double, _
                                              ByVal sigma As Double, _
                                              ByVal t As Double, _
                                              ByVal nSize As Long, _
                                              ByRef STerminal() As Double)

  Dim i As Long
  Dim Drift As Double
  Dim SigmaSqrtT As Double

  'This creates the drift term of the stock price
  Drift = (r - 0.5 * sigma * sigma) * t

  'This creates the Standard Brownian Motion parameter
  SigmaSqrtT = sigma * (t ^ 0.5)

  'The following creates simulated terminal price values for purposes of Monte Carlo Simulation
  For i = 1 To nSize
    STerminal(i) = sNaught * Exp(Drift + SigmaSqrtT * Excel.WorksheetFunction.NormSInv(Rnd()))
  Next i

End Sub

'Creates the probability of shortfall equation
Function Prshortfall(sNaught As Double, r As Double, sigma As Double, t As Double, n As Double)

  'Creating variables of use in the equation
  Dim i As Long
  Dim V() As Variant
  Dim terminalstockprices() As Double
  Dim probability As Double
  Dim variance As Double
  Dim sum As Double
  Dim squaredvalue As Double
  Dim totalvalue As Double
  Dim riskfree As Double
  Dim ret As Double
  Dim averagevalue As Double

  'Specifying parameters of arrays
  ReDim V(1, 1 To 3) As Variant
  ReDim terminalstockprices(n) As Double

  'Setting initial values to 0 for certain variables
  riskfree = 0.02
  sum = 0#
  squaredvalue = 0#
  totalvalue = 0#


  'Generating the terminal values.  Notice that the array is passed by reference
  Call GenerateRandomTerminalStockPrices(sNaught, r, sigma, t, n, terminalstockprices)

  'Tests each terminal stock price in relation to the risk free rate and keeps count if less than risk free rate
  For i = 1 To n
    totalvalue = totalvalue + terminalstockprices(i)
    squaredvalue = squaredvalue + terminalstockprices(i) * terminalstockprices(i)
    ret = (terminalstockprices(i) / sNaught) - 1
    If ret < riskfree Then
      sum = sum + 1
    End If
  Next i

  'Solves for probability, average price, and price variance based on the outcome of simulation
  probability = sum / n
  averagevalue = totalvalue / n
  variance = (squaredvalue - averagevalue * sum) / (n - 1)

  'Outputs the probability, average price, and price standard error
  V(1, 1) = probability
  V(1, 2) = averagevalue
  V(1, 3) = Sqr(variance / n)

  Prshortfall = V

End Function
```

I've tested the code using =prshortfall(100,0.02,0.04,1,100) but only get an output of 0 in one cell as opposed to 3 outputs of probability, average price, and price standard error that I was expecting to get.

Does anyone have any suggestions on where there may be a coding issue or an input error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Option Base 1` at top of module.

Or change the v line to

`Dim v(1 to 1,1 to 3)`

Excuse me, I removed the first Dim v() As Variant and do I'm not Redimming in my version.

Answer (score 1):

The easy answer is that you need an array to get the output.

Select B1:D1 and enter your

```
=prshortfall(100,0.02,0.04,1,100)
```

Then CSE it and you have your numbers.

> Array formulas need to be confirmed via <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.

[image]

**EDIT**
I forgot that i changed the line

```
Prshortfall = V
```

with

```
Prshortfall = Array(probability, averagevalue, Sqr(variance / n))
```

So this solution only would work if a range of 2 rows is used (like A1:B3). Sorry for that :P

Comment: Thank you! Although it still outputs 3 zeros which I'm not sure of the reasoning for this.

Comment: @Trevor I completely missed this... I messed around with your code and replaced `Prshortfall = V` with `Prshortfall = Array(probability, averagevalue, Sqr(variance / n))`... sorry for that :P

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the format of the cell(s)?

```
Sub Test()

    Dim a As Variant

    a = Prshortfall(100, 0.02, 0.04, 1, 100)

End Sub
```

**a** contains the following:

[image: a contains]

You'll have to catch the values of **a(1,1)**, **a(1,2)** and **a(1,3)** and set them in the cells. It's maybe neccessary to change the format of these cells to *numbers with decimal places*.

**Edit**

```
'Solves for probability, average price, and price variance based on the outcome of simulation
  probability = sum / n
  averagevalue = totalvalue / n
  variance = (squaredvalue - averagevalue * sum) / (n - 1)

  'Outputs the probability, average price, and price standard error
  V(1, 1) = probability
  V(1, 2) = averagevalue
  V(1, 3) = Sqr(variance / n)

  '3 results are in one variable and is the return value
  Prshortfall = V(1, 1) & " " & V(1, 2) & " " & V(1, 3)

End Function
```

**Result**

[image: the result in a cell]

Comment: Hmmh so it looks like the code is doing what I want.  Could it be an issue of how I'm typing in the formula in Excel?  

Right now I'm just typing in = Prshortfall(100, 0.02, 0.04, 1, 100), I've read that you may have to hit ctrl + shift + enter?

Comment: The result is an array which contains more than just **one** number. Try this: **Prshortfall = V(1, 1) & " | " & V(1, 2) & " | " & V(1, 3)** in your code. Now you'll have the 3 results in one cell ... you'll have to split each number apart from the others and set it maybe via VBA. Another way is splitting the calculations in 3 different functions. I've edited my answer with this example.

Comment: Ah, interesting.  That is a unique way to do it.  I'll what I can do.

Comment: Dirk Reichel's answer is something I didn't know. It's easier and you were right with your thoughts. :)